# Name Value List with Value field as Rich Text

Tags: content-editor, fieldtype

Is it possible to have the Value field of the NAME-VALUE list as the RichText?

Our Requirement is to provide the HTML content in the Value field and render in the webpage as HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Not really, no

While it may be possible to tweak some stuff around to make it seem like it works, I doubt it would really be a solution for you in the long run.

Internally, a `Name Value Field` stores its value as an `UrlString`. As such there are limitations to both length and actual content you can put in the field.

> The raw value of Name Value List is stored in a url string format – value_1=20.5&value_2=21.5&value_3=22.5&value_4=23.5&value_5=24.5.

And in code, when reading the field value:

```
string _urlParamsToParse = item["NameValueListFieldName"];
NameValueCollection nameValueCollection = Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.ParseUrlParameters(_urlParamsToParse);
```

You should probably re-visit whatever requirement it is, you're pursuing.